# Annotate query set with field value

Tags: django, multilingual, annotate

Multilanguage website with translations stored in columns of one table.
Need to pass query set to template with already filtered translations.
Language variable is stored in session.

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    description = models.ForeignKey(Localization)

class Localization(models.Model):
    klingon = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='klingon')
    english = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='english')
```

Thought would be nice just to annotate the qs with the needed text, however I failed to find how to annotate with a field value. Something like

```
item = Item.objects.all().annotate(text=description.klingon)
```

Another approach would be to use a template filter like

```
item.description|choose_lang:request
```

but sorting the qs before the template seems neater.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the F() expression here

```
from django.db.models import F    
item = Item.objects.all().annotate(text=F('description__klingon'))
```

[Source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations)

Comment: Thank you. I tried these F things by myself, but It turned out that I made a mistake in a different place of the code and when it failed I figured that I had this F instructions wrong :) Now all works fine.

Comment: con I also get all fields from the Localization model using F instead of writing all the fields one by one ??

Comment: Query could do without calling `all()`, therefore becoming: `Item.objects.annotate(text=F('description__klingon'))`